# Riemann Branch Points and Covering

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-points

I am currently struggling with understanding how to find the branch points and behavior of covering of implicitly defined irreducible functions $P(x,y)$.
An arbitrary example I am working on is to find the branch points and branching of
$$P(x,y) = x^4 -4xy +3y^2$$
As I understand, branch points are at points $(x_0,y_0)$ where $P(x_0,y_0) = \partial x P(x_0,y_0) = 0$

So, in this case, the branch points would be given by the system: $$x^3 = y$$ $$x^4 -4x^4 +3x^6 = 0$$

And thus we have $$x^3 = y$$
$$3x^3(x^2-1)=0$$
So the branch points would be (0,0), (1,1), (-1, -1).

Now, I am interested in the branch behavior, and how the Riemann sheets are distributed. From what I understand, the degree of $x$ in $P(x,y)$ is the number of Riemann sheets at each branch point $y_0$. How would I determine the branch behavior?

I have gathered from an example that you find all zeroes of $P(x,y_0)$, where $y_0$ is a branch point, and the order of the zero at each $y_0$ is the number of sheets at that point. I don't completely understand why/if this is true.

Moreover, I have seen an example of Riemann sheets "grouping", as in $P(x,y) = w^6 - (z-3)^3(z+2)^2$. (Figuring out the sheet behavior was not explained) Are the sheets determined in the same "find roots and multiplicities" way?

I suppose my principal question here is, how can you figure out "branching behavior" and Riemann covers for a general polynomial? I cannot find any resources on it, so any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're considering the sheets of the Riemann surface over the $y$-plane. One way is to find the Puiseux series in $y$ near each branch point. Near $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, the method of dominant balance gives either $x (x^3 - 4 y)$ or $y (-4 x + 3 y)$, so we get three connected branches and one regular branch (in general, we might also need the subsequent terms). Near $(x, y) = (\infty, \infty)$, dominant balance gives $x^4 + 3 y^2$, which is not irreducible, so we get two pairs of connected branches. We can repeat the same analysis for the remaining two branch points.